# Hinge Settings II: The Wrath of Clang - Why does just *touching* the 'minimum angle' setting cause my entire grid to explode?

Tags: space-engineers

Someone on a server I am running reports a reportable clang-inducing event that involves setting a minimum angle for a rotor.

The rig in question is: Piston->Adv. Rotor->Hinge->Drill + Drill.

The hinge, before the first explosion, was at roughly 40-degrees and locked. But after the explosion my friend rebuilt it, started it up, and again tried to set a minimum angle on the rotor, this time resulting in an even larger explosion.

We're running out of material now, so before we go build this a third time, is this a known issue with hinges that I can't find via Googling for it, or is there some other obvious thing that's probably going wrong?  How do we even troubleshoot this?

Editing to add a prior event which involved a rotor with a small subgrid device on it (I think it was an ore detector), which also exploded (and took a big chunk of the voxel material with it) the instant the 'minimum angle' setting was touched.

Possibly related: I had a vertical-axis rotor on a solar array when when I *unset* a prior minimum angle setting while the thing had velocity, it suddenly whirled around at RPM I can only describe as "will it blend?" It didn't blow up, and slowed down and behaved itself rapidly thereafter, but it sure was exciting for a hot second.

Comment: Are you sharing the inertia tensor on the hinges, pistons, and rotor? When I have multiple sub-grid parts connected like that, they get very clangy very quickly unless I check that box on all of the moving parts.

Comment: The server has since crashed, but if I end up in the same sitch, I'll give this a try, for sure!